# Counting txt files from subdirectories of given path and contains a given string

Tags: c++, c, file, operating-system, directory

How can I count the number of txt files that contain a given string in C or C++, within a given path, in all of his subdirectories?

I want to only run the program from cmd by giving the name of the c files and two arguments with the path from where I want to search, and the string that the file must contain.

Comment: Do you know how to read a line of text in a file?

Comment: Here is an example of searching a string into a file:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/3710/

Comment: I already know how to do it.  I am asking if **YOU** Know how.  So I can explain the process to you instead of writting it for you.

Comment: I didn't understood the purpose of the question at the first look sorry. I'm a begginer at programming with files and directories.

Comment: If you don't know how to read a file line by line you need to research how to do that before I can help you.  We expect a certain level of research to be done before asking a question.  If you cannot even read a file how can you expect to read every file in a given directory?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the right system calls : `opendir()`, `readdir()`, `closedir()`. They will let you iterate over directory entries...